# Telegram bot doesn't recieve messages from a channel

Tags: telegram-bot

Private settings are turned off.

the bot is added to the channel and he is an admin.

i created another channel because maybe the other one had problems but it didn't helped too.

And it still can't see the messages i send in the channel , why?
(i tested it and he gets the messages everywhere except of channels)

Comment: considar that `channel_post` is a different update parameter than `message` in https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider that `channel_post` is a different update parameter than regular `message` parameter which is only for private chats and groups.

check more in: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates